# SKCurrentPositionListener not working, onCurrentPositionUpdate not reached in SKMaps

Tags: android, gps, location, listener, skmaps

The app was working fine while trying to update using the SKCurrentPositionListener.

After I installed in emulator, and again re-installing on real device, I am not able to get the current location.

```
currentPositionProvider = new SKCurrentPositionProvider(this);
currentPositionProvider.setCurrentPositionListener(this);
currentPositionProvider.requestLocationUpdates(MapUtils.hasGpsModule(this), MapUtils.hasNetworkModule(this), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check our AndroidOpenSourceDemo.
`MapActivity.java` implements `SKCurrentPositionListener` and whenever you get a position you have to call

```
mapView.reportNewGPSPosition(currentPosition);
```

in order the SDK to have your current GPS position.